# IntentService does not work android

Tags: android, intentservice

My code receives no crash errors. When I run the App and click the button, a Toast should show, but it doesn't.

Here is my `IntentService`

```
package com.example.flas;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.flas.JSONParser;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SampleIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int DOWNLOAD_ERROR = 10;
    public static final int DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS = 11;

    String latbus;
    String lonbus;
    String latsta;
    String Employernumber;
    String lonsta;
    String numrout;

    String nomsta;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String url_product_detials = "http://********/get_loc_details2.php";

    private static final String TAG_IDLOCBUS = "idlocbus";

    private static final String TAG_BUSNUMBER = "BusNumber";

    private static final String TAG_BUSLATITUDE = "BusLatitude";

    private static final String TAG_BUSLONGITUDE = "Buslongitude";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";

    public SampleIntentService() {
        super(SampleIntentService.class.getName());
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");

        final ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        try {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", url));

            // getting JSON Object

            // Note that create product url accepts POST method

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(

            url_product_detials, "GET", params);

            // check log cat fro response

            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag

            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            // successfully received product details

            JSONArray productObj = json

            .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

            // get first product object from JSON Array

            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

            // product with this pid found

            // display product data in EditText

            String aa = product.getString(TAG_IDLOCBUS);

            String bb = product.getString(TAG_BUSNUMBER);

            String latb = product.getString(TAG_BUSLATITUDE);

            String lonb = product.getString(TAG_BUSLONGITUDE);

            bundle.putString("filePath", lonb + latb);
            receiver.send(DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS, bundle);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            receiver.send(DOWNLOAD_ERROR, Bundle.EMPTY);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

My `MainActivity` that calls my `IntentService`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ProgressBar pd;
    SampleResultReceiver resultReceiever;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        resultReceiever = new SampleResultReceiver(new Handler());

        pd = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.downloadPD);

    }

    private class SampleResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

        public SampleResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (resultCode) {
            case SampleIntentService.DOWNLOAD_ERROR: {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error in download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
                break;

            case SampleIntentService.DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS: {
                String filePath = resultData.getString("filePath");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image download via IntentService is done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                pd.setIndeterminate(false);
                pd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
                break;
            }
            super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SampleIntentService.class);

        startIntent.putExtra("receiver", resultReceiever);
        String aaa = "5";
        startIntent.putExtra("url", aaa);

        startService(startIntent);

        pd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    public void onClick2(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image download via IntentService is done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

My JSON Class works fine, I tried it in another App and I got not error.

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` ...

I tried this:

```
<service android:name="com.example.pfecuspart.SampleIntentService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="org.example.android.myservicedemo.IService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I also tried this:

```
<service android:name="com.example.pfecuspart.SampleIntentService"
    android:enabled="true">
</service>
```

Comment: please tell us where the error is located

Comment: that's the prob the intentservice doesn't work coz when i click at button (onClick) the toast doesn't show so i create another button onClick2 and when i press on it .. the toast shows..

Comment: my problem in onReceiveResult why the toast in onReceiveResult not working :'(

Comment: i find the solution, the error was in  bundle .. so i added bundle.putString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Error message here..");

Answer (score 0):

I dont think onClick2 is doing anything, its not overriding the onClick.
do you need to move;

```
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
     "image download via IntentService is done",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

from onClick2, to onClick. 
Maybe try replacing `getApplicationContext()` with `MainActivity.this`

Comment: onClick2  is doing nothing coz i just try it to make sure that getApplicationContext() is right so it works but the problem in other toast

Comment: Which other toast is in an onClick()  ?

Comment: do a System.out.println(resultCode); to see what the code actually is, and if it actually matched what it should be.

Comment: even they are not matched i did not get the error toast thx anyways ^^

Comment: If they are not a match then you are expecting the wrong result